# Backed an ipod up with dd, how to retrieve all tracks in one go with gnupod?

Tags: command-line, dd, ipod, gtkpod

I have had [gnupod](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnupod/) for a while. Still haven't figured out how to use it though. I usually just go for gtkpod. So this question, in case anyone had any doubts after reading everything below, *is purely about gnupod syntax*.

Recently I decided to [get my ipod replaced](http://www.apple.com/support/ipodnano_replacement/) under this replacement scheme. (I don't like proprietary hardware, etc., but if someone is going to give me a brand new piece of hardware... for something that was originally a gift... hmm...)

Anyway, long story short, I backed up my old ipod using dd:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb2 of=ipodbk
```

and just tried running gtkpod (with ipodbk mounted as `-t vfat -o loop`) to see if it would pick it up, like it does when an ipod is attached, which it does.

But this question is not about that.

I don't want to waste time with gtkpod's bugginess when it comes to exporting an entire ipod's files (tried it before. ended up with a lot of 0 byte files... no thanks).

I just want to be able to export all the tracks from the disk image in one go.

The command probably looks something like

```
gnupod_something (some switches) -m /home/user/ipodbkmount/ (some stuff?)
```

and the output probably looks something like

```
(window flooded with 1000 lines of text)
```

but I've never really been able to get `gnupod` to work. I'm sure it's a great program, and I have to usually invoke it as `gnupod_check -m ipod --fixit` once in a while when `gtkpod` loses track of what it's doing and makes errors when it writes files to the device. As for `gnupod`, I'm just not intelligent enough to figure out its syntax on the more routine ipod manipulations, I think.

So, yeah, what's that command?

Comment: What does `file ipodbk` say about the format?

Comment: Can't you see all your files if you simply mount that image? (`mount -o loop -t vfat your_image /mount/point`)

Comment: Well, honestly there's way too much unrelated "stuff" in your question. If you cut everything down to the `dd` part, the fact that you can mount it but don't see your music files in there, _and_ show how you're launching `gnupod` and what error (if any) it's giving you, you wouldn't have confused me. Strip your question down to the essential.

Comment: @Mat I'm sorry, but I think you not knowing what I'm talking about is the case here. You don't 'see' an ipod's files, apple hides them for you inside an encrypted database. And you don't 'launch' gnupod, you invoke it, like any shell program. So please feel free to ignore this question.

Comment: @ixtmixilix I think *you* don't know what you're talking about. The files are in the subdirectories within iTunes_Control/Music.  They are just named funny, get a program to rename them (if you care) and you're set.

Comment: From root, it's /private/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/Music (or without the private, `var` is a symlink there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, gnupod does not work directly with the iPod database, you need to convert from and to the gnupod database, so you want to run `tunes2pod.pl` first. This only needs to be done when you change the iTunesDB (iPod's own database) directly — if you use gnupod again without using other tool, you don't need to run this again.

(Likewise, if you use gnupod to change the database, you need to run `mktunes.pl`, which updates the iTunesDB.)

When you already have the gnupod format database (which is stored in the iPod just like the iTunesDB):

If what you want is to get the track information, no files, you want to use `gnupod_search.pl` (the gnupod tool to search the db and edit entries).

Have a look at the manpage, because you can tune what it shows, including the path to the files themselves (but from your comments it seems you don't need this).

IIRC, running it with no arguments (other than the mountpoint and related iPod configuration stuff) dumps the whole list of entries.

If you want to search, there are several arguments that go like `--title=the-string`, `--artist=the-string`. `title` and `artist` are "keys", and you can use `--rename="key=value"` to change the value associated to that key in the matched entries. There's also `--delete` that, well, deletes whatever matches the search parameters.

Oh, and, for a quick introduction to an iPod manager, what else... oh, right, add songs: `gnupod_addsong.pl`, it takes the names of the media files and copies these to the iPod. Has several options (e.g. to override the title) and, if you have the required dependencies, it may even be able to convert other formats such as ogg (although you probably need to specify `--decode=format`, where the format can be, among others, mp3).

(If you end up using gnupod as your iPod manager, you can put the mountpoint and model information in `~/.gnupodrc` to save some typing.)

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but can the iPod use the gnupod database? How does it know about the new database?

Comment: Found the answer by reading the man. https://www.gnu.org/software/gnupod/gnupod.html#SEC18 The gnupod db is converted back to iTunesDB by the user before ejecting.